# JAVA UTC to EST from a long UTC timestamp

Tags: java, datetime, utc

I'm trying to convert a long timestamp that is UTC to Eastern Standard Time and am totally lost.  Any hints would be great!

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Date estTime = new Date(utcTime.getTime() + TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST").getRawOffset());
```

Where utcTime is Date object of UTC time (if you already have the long value - just use it)

Comment: I thought use of the Date class was discouraged.

Comment: Calendar creation can be quite expensive, that's i don't like using it. If performance is not an issue using it is also an option.

Comment: Like this:
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy h:mm a");
String formatted = format.format(utcTime);
System.out.println(formatted);

Comment: What about DST?

Answer (score 3):

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
c.setTimeInMillis(longTime);
```

Where `longTime` is the number of milliseconds since the epoch in UTC time. You can then use the methods of the [Calendar](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class to get the various components of the date/time.

Answer (score 1):

rd42, Can you give me a little more context on this?

You say you have a "UTC timestamp".  Is this stored in a database?  Is it a string?

I might be able to provide you more of an answer if you can give the context you're trying to work this in.

---

Ok for clarity's sake what you're saying is that you have a long value that represents a timestamp in UTC.

So in that case what you're going to want to do is the following.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

TimeZone utcTZ= TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
Calendar utcCal= Calendar.getInstance(utcTZ);
utcCal.setTimeInMillis(utcAsLongValue);
```

Now you're calendar object is in UTC.

To display this though you're going to want to do something like the following:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz");
sdf.setTimeZone(utcTZ);
Date utcDate= utcCal.getTime();
sdf.formatDate(utcDate);
```

This will allow you to read in a timestamp for the UTC time zone stored as a long value and convert it to a Java Calendar or Date object.

Hope that gets you where you need to be.

Comment: The variable is of type long with a UTC timestamp.  Trying to change it from 1271101959000 to something more friendly.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution using, `java.time` the modern API

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline. It is independent of a timezone. In order to represent it in a timezone, you can use [`Instant#atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-) or [`ZonedDateTime#ofInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#ofInstant-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-) as shown below:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A sample timestamp
        long millis = 1620999618896L;

        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis);
        System.out.println(instant);

        ZonedDateTime zdtET = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(zdtET);

        // Alternatively
        zdtET = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(zdtET);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-05-14T13:40:18.896Z
2021-05-14T09:40:18.896-04:00[America/New_York]
2021-05-14T09:40:18.896-04:00[America/New_York]
```

The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

**Note:** For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `Instant` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

Learn more about the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>