# Converting date from UTC to EST in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert a long timestamp that is UTC to Eastern Standard Time and am totally lost. Any hints would be great!

Time format should be : 11/4/03 8:14 PM 
Thanks in advance!

```
TimeZone utcTZ= TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
Calendar utcCal= Calendar.getInstance(utcTZ);
utcCal.setTimeInMillis(utcAsLongValue);



import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz");
sdf.setTimeZone(utcTZ);
Date utcDate= utcCal.getTime();
sdf.formatDate(utcDate);
```

Comment: TimeZone utcTZ= TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
Calendar utcCal= Calendar.getInstance(utcTZ);
utcCal.setTimeInMillis(utcAsLongValue);


import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz");
sdf.setTimeZone(utcTZ);
Date utcDate= utcCal.getTime();
sdf.formatDate(utcDate);

Comment: Please add it to your answer, and try to keep it formatted, no-one is going to read it that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAVA UTC to EST from a long UTC timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624610/java-utc-to-est-from-a-long-utc-timestamp)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yesterday occasionally I wrote the following method that can help you:

```
private Date shiftTimeZone(Date date, TimeZone sourceTimeZone, TimeZone targetTimeZone) {
    Calendar sourceCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    sourceCalendar.setTime(date);
    sourceCalendar.setTimeZone(sourceTimeZone);

    Calendar targetCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    for (int field : new int[] {Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.MILLISECOND}) {
        targetCalendar.set(field, sourceCalendar.get(field));
    }
    targetCalendar.setTimeZone(targetTimeZone);

    return targetCalendar.getTime();
}
```

Now you just have to format the date. Use SimpleDateFormat for this. Here is the example:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh:mm a");
format.format(date);
```

Comment: Try this and see if you get correct "conversion" to EST (UTC-5): `System.err.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yy/M/dd hh:mm a z").format(shiftTimeZone(new Date(), TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"), TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"))));`. It doesn't work correctly.

Comment: It does not print the correct time in EST from current time in GMT. It prints a time 2 hours behind EST. Did you try it?

Answer (score 7):

You should not think in terms of converting a Date to a different timezone. Dates in Java are, and should always be, in UTC.

Rather, you can set a particular timezone when you want to **format** a Date. Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String tzid = "EST";
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(tzid);

    long utc = System.currentTimeMillis();  // supply your timestamp here
    Date d = new Date(utc);

    // timezone symbol (z) included in the format pattern for debug
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/M/dd hh:mm a z");

    // format date in default timezone
    System.err.println(format.format(d));

    // format date in target timezone
    format.setTimeZone(tz);
    System.err.println(format.format(d));

}
```

Output for me (my default timezone is GMT):

```
11/12/19 10:06 AM GMT
11/12/19 05:06 AM EST
```

Alternatively, you can set the timezone on a Calendar, and then access the Calendar fields you require. For example:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
    c.setTimeInMillis(utc);
    System.err.printf("%d/%d/%d %d:%d %s\n", c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), c.get(Calendar.HOUR), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), (c.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM ? "AM" : "PM"));
```

(This does not give you the exact pattern you requested.)

Answer (score 3):

Timezone conversion can be tricky. You should probably use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html) where timezone tables are constantly updated (and can be updated manually if needed

Using Joda time it is pretty easy:

```
public static Date convertJodaTimezone(LocalDateTime date, String localTimeZone, String destTimeZone) {
  DateTime srcDateTime = date.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID(localTimeZone));
  DateTime dstDateTime = srcDateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(destTimeZone));
  return dstDateTime.toLocalDateTime().toDateTime().toDate();
}
```

with timezones from the following [table](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html)

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood Java keeps date value in UTC milliseconds so I think only way to shift value is by manipulating these millies e.g.

```
private void getShiftedDate(Date date, TimeZone targetZone) {
    long sourceMillies = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset());
    long targetMillies = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(targetZone.getRawOffset());

    long newMillies = date.getTime() + (targetMillies - sourceMillies);
    Date shiftedDate = new Date(newMillies);
    System.out.println("shifted => " + shiftedDate);
}
```

However, toString() of shiftedDate will still print default/source time zone string.