# How to convert timezone from UTC to other timezone i.e. EDT or EST java

Tags: java

I am storing time in milliseconds into *UTC format* and while showing it, and later I am converting back into the user timezone.

But I'm getting date one day less than what I have stored in the Db.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting date from UTC to EST in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559165/converting-date-from-utc-to-est-in-java)

Comment: Can you post the code you have?

Comment: public static long getDateInMiliseconds(String dateStr) {
  long dateInMiliseconds = 0;
  String defaultTimeZone = "UTC";
  String dateFormatStr =""MM-dd-yyyy"; 
   
   DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatStr);
   formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(defaultTimeZone));
   Date date = formatter.parse(dateStr);
   dateInMiliseconds = date.getTime();
  
  return dateInMiliseconds;
 }

i am using this to get date in millis from date.